# Rudin's PMA: problem 2.17

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I'm reading Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis and trying problem 17 of chapter 2.

> Let $E$ be the set of all $x\in [0,1]$ whose decimal expansion contains only the digits $4$ and $7$. Is $E$ countable? Is $E$ dense in $[0,1]$? Is $E$ compact? Is $E$ perfect?

My argument is the following:

1. Is $E$ countable? No. - Use Cantor's diagonal process as in the proof of theorem 2.14 of baby Rudin: Take a countable subset of $E$, namely $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and construct a sequence whose $n$-th member is $7$ if $n$-th digit of $a_n$ is $4$ and $4$ if $n$-th digit of $a_n$ is $7$. Then this new sequence differs from any other member of $A$. Thus every countable subset of $E$ is proper, it follows that $E$ is uncountable (for otherwise $E$ would be a proper subset of $E$).
2. Is $E$ dense in $[0,1]$? No. - There's no member of $E$ between $0.1$ and $0.2$: Because it must start with $0.1...$ and $1$ is not allowed for a member of $E$.
3. Is $E$ compact? No. - Since by theorem 2.34 of baby Rudin, compact subsets of metric spaces are closed. So if $E$ is not closed, then it must not be compact. I will show that $E^c$ is not open. Take $x\in E^c$. Then we need to find a open ball $B_r(x)=\{y\in [0,1]:|x-y|<r\}$. But for every $r>0$, $B_r(x)$ must contain a number at least one of whose digits contains $4$ or $7$; otherwise there would be a gap inside the ball (a segment, actually). So  $E$ is not closed (since $E$ closed $\iff$ $E^c$ open).
4. Is $E$ perfect? No. - Direct from the definition: a perfect set is a closed set whose members are limit points.

Is my argument valid?

Comment: E is closed, so your argument for (3) is incorrect. Specifically, you wrote "For every $r>0$, $B_r(x)$ must contain at least one of whose digits contains $4$ or $7$", but the digits of that number may not contain $4$ and $7$ _only_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your application of Cantor's diagonal process is correct.
2. Nice observation that $[0.1,0.2] \subseteq E^\complement$.
3. $E$ is in fact closed.  Take $x = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots} \in E^\complement$, where the $n$-th decimal place $a_n \in \{0,\dots,9\}$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.  Since $x \notin E$, there exists $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_m \notin \{4, 7\}$.  Let's choose the *least* possible value of $m$, and choose $r$ sufficiently small so that $B_r(x) \subseteq E^\complement$ by defining $r = \color{red}{\frac{1}{100}\min}\{|x - c_i| \mid i \in \{1,\dots,4\}\}$.  Observe that $E$ is "locally bounded" by the intervals $[c_1,c_2]$ and $[c_3,c_4]$.

   $$\bbox[36px, yellow, border: 2px solid red]{\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
   \rlap{\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} {\Large [} & {\large \bullet} & \llap{\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} {\Large ]} & {\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} & {\Large |} {\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} & {\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} {\Large |}  & {\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} & \rlap{\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} {\Large [} & {\large \bullet} & \llap{\style{display: inline-block; transform: scale(10,1)}{-}} {\Large ]} \\
   c_1 & \begin{matrix}\uparrow \\ E\end{matrix} & c_2 & \rlap{\small\overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}}5/6}} & & & & c_3 & \begin{matrix}\uparrow \\ E\end{matrix} & c_4
   \end{array}}\\
   \text{Figure 1: range of possible values of numbers in $E$}$$

   - $c_1 = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}} \color{red}{4}4}$
   - $c_2 = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}} \color{red}{4}8}$
   - $c_3 = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}} \color{red}{7}4}$
   - $c_4 = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}} \color{red}{7}8}$

   Recall that $x = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots a_{\color{red}{m-1}} a_m a_{m+1} a_{m+2} \cdots}$, so $$r \le \frac{44 \cdot 10^{-(m+1)}}{100} < \frac{50 \cdot 10^{-(m+1)}}{100} = \frac{5}{10^{m+2}}.$$  When we add/minus $r$ to/from $x$, the new number $x \pm r$ "*won't* differ too much from $x$".  Consider $x - r$ ( or $x + r$).  Either one of the following cases occurs:

   - the $m$-th decimal place is *still* $a_m \notin \{4,7\}$, so $x - r \notin E$.
   - the $m$-th decimal place is *changed* by $1$ (digit $0 \to 9$ also counts).  A *necessary* condition for this to happen is that $a_{m+1} \in \{0,9\}$.  (To see this, imagine examples like $0.95 + 0.05 = 1$.)  In this case, the $(m + 1)$-th decimal place of $x-r$ would be either $0$ or $9$, so $x - r \notin E$.

   Thus, any number in $B_r(x)$ *can't* belong to $E$.  Therefore, $E^\complement$ is open and $E$ is closed.  Since $E$ is bounded, Heine–Borel Theorem tells us that $E$ is compact.

   Your mistake is the wrong deduction from "$B_r(x)$ must contain a number at least one of whose digits contains $4$ or $7$" to "$E^\complement$ is *not* open".  To be a member of $E$, the decimal $y \in B_r(x)$ should consist *merely* in digits $4$ and $7$, not just "at least one" digit.

   Remarks: The choice of $r$ is a bit *tricky* and the verification is a bit *tedious*, but it's still *doable*.
4. $E$ is NOT a perfect set.  The idea that $$0.4\overset{\bullet}{7}, 0.44\overset{\bullet}{7}, 0.444\overset{\bullet}{7}, \cdots \to 0.\overset{\bullet}{4}$$ only holds for a member of $E$ which is a non-terminating decimal.  In that case, each term $0.4\dots4\overset{\bullet}{7}$ on LHS contains digit $7$, so it's different from RHS $0.\overset{\bullet}{4}$, and thus it lies in a *deleted* neighbourhood of $0.\overset{\bullet}{4}$.  To finish the argument, just repeat this idea for *any* $x \in E$ which is a non-terminating decimal.

   For any $x = \overline{0.a_1a_2\cdots} \in E$ which is a **non-terminating decimal**, I'm going to construct a sequence $(y_n)_n$ in $E$ so that $\lim\limits_n y_n = x$.  For all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, define $y_n = \overline{0.b_1b_2\cdots b_{m-1} b_m b_{m+1}}$, where $$b_m = \begin{cases} a_m \quad &\text{ if } m \le n \\ \max(\{4,7\}\setminus\{a_m\}) & \text{ if } m > n \end{cases}.$$ $\require{HTML}$
   $$
   \bbox[yellow, 5px, border: 2px solid red]{
   \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
   x & = & 0. & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & a_n & a_{n+1} & \cdots \\
   \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\ne} & & & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{=} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{=} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{=} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{=} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{=} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\ne} & \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\ne} \\
   y_n & = & 0. & b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_{n-1} & b_n & b_{n+1} & \cdots
   \end{array}} \\
   \text{Figure 2: construction of approaching sequence $(y_n)_n$ in $E'$ from $x \in E$}
   $$
   It's clear that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $y_n \ne x$ and $y_n \in E$, but $\lim\limits_n y_n = x$, so $x \in E'$.

   If $x \in E$ is a **terminating decimal**, as Josie's comment below suggests, just take a "suitably small" $r$ to that $B_r(x)\setminus\{x\} \subset E^\complement$, say to take $x = 0.4$ and $r = 0.02$, so that the deleted neighbourhood becomes $(0.38, 0.4) \cup (0.4, 0.42)$, which contains no member of $E$.

Comment: I don't think it's OK to answer a proof-verification question with an alternative proof _only_. You should state the error the OP made in the first place.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thanks for comments.  I've [edit]ed my answer to reflect your comments.  Cheers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Hi, I'm trying to show a bit directly that every limit point of $E$ in fact belongs to $E$, namely $E'\subset E$, to see that $E$ is closed. My argument is the folloing: Take $l\in E'$. Then $l$ is a limit point of $E$, so for every open nbhd $U$ of $l$, $U\setminus \{l\}\cap E\not=\varnothing$. And since we are discussing in $\mathbb{R}$, we can take $U=(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. And we can even choose specific sequence of $\epsilon$, i.e., $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{10^n}$. So let $U_n=(l-\epsilon_n, l+\epsilon_n)$.

Comment: For each $n$, we know that $U_n\setminus \{l\}\cap E\not=\varnothing$. So for some $x=\overline{0.a_1a_2a_3...}\in U_n\setminus \{l\}\cap E$ ($a_i\in\{4,7\}$), we are guaranteed that $l$ has the same decimal expansion as $x$ up to $n$-th decimal. This is true for each $n$. Now I only need to say that $l$ consists of $4$ and $7$ and conclude that it belongs to $E$, but Rudin never gave us sequencial definition of a limit point, but a topological definition I used above. Should I use induction here? If $l$ consists of finite decimals, no problem is caused.

Comment: What I am difficult to accept is about infinite decimal ones. How can I be sure about that infinite ones also consist only of $4$ and $7$?

Comment: @user642721 Under metric topology, sequential convergence criterion suffices.  For the last question, I just _construct_ one.  I admit that the notation used while defining $b_m$ isn't elegant, but I don't know a better way to write that in symbols.  I should have included an example like $0.7, 0.47, 0.447, 0.4447, ... \to 0.4444....$.

Comment: I prefer borrowing English words for further explaining stuff.  Let's call $U_n\setminus \{l\}$ *deleted $\epsilon_n$-neighbourhood about $\ell$*. The elementary topological definition "$\forall n: U_n\setminus \{l\}\cap E\not=\varnothing$" simply means that "no matter how small our radius $\epsilon_n$ is, you can always find an element in $E$ belonging to the deleted $\epsilon_n$-neighbourhood about $\ell$"  Note that the limit point $\ell \in E'$ is _fixed_ in the definition.  Forget about _deleted_ for the moment, so you simply need a sequence $b_n \to \ell$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Translated to words: no matter how small $\epsilon_n$-nhbd about $\ell$ is, the "*tail*" of $b_n$ stays inside the small $\epsilon_n$-nhbd.  If you can prove that $\forall n: b_n \ne \ell$, then $(b_n)_n$ belongs to a _deleted_ nbhd about $\ell$ for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92990/discussion-between-gnusupporter-8964--and-user642721).

Comment: I don’t think E is perfect. Every point of a perfect set must be a limit point, but every point of E with a finite decimal expansion is not a limit point of E. Take for example .4 - then the neighborhood of .02 about .4 contains no other points of E, so .4 cannot be a limit point.

Comment: @JosieThompson thx 4 comment i've edited my ans.